# Decompress NSString to xml in objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, xml, compression

I'm having a stirng like below...

```
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
```

I need to convert this string to an XML.

I'd tried to decompress the string by getting the byte array from the string using base64 encoding. But I failed to move on. I don't think I'm in the right path. I searched a lot for any libraries found for NSString decompression. But no luck.

The input string is valid one. I succeed with [online string decompress](http://www.unit-conversion.info/texttools/compress/) to xml.

Comment: Yours online tool gives me nothing from yours string. Also it's not base64 encoded string.

Comment: @Cy-4AH, I've dited the question with full string....Pl check

Comment: Have you tried to decompress data with zlib after base64 decoding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is XML data that was compressed with zlib to the zlib format, and then Base64 encoded. You need to decode the Base64, then decompress with zlib. Then you get:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ThreeDSecure><Message id="PAReq-tdnD8zqWDC"><PARes id="lQCkUVS06gWpyMR8uKCL"><version>1.0.2</version><Merchant><acqBIN>494000</acqBIN><merID>123456789</merID></Merchant><Purchase><xid>fregBoJ/QFmCwyPNUO3/czQ4NTM=</xid><date>20170120 12:39:40</date><purchAmount>92400</purchAmount><currency>682</currency><exponent>2</exponent></Purchase><pan>0000000000002349</pan><TX><time>20170125 06:56:08</time><status>Y</status><cavv>MDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDA=</cavv><eci>05</eci><cavvAlgorithm>1</cavvAlgorithm></TX></PARes><Signature xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#"><SignedInfo xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#"><CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315"/><SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1"/><Reference URI="#lQCkUVS06gWpyMR8uKCL"><DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"/><DigestValue>hbDuU8EtfIpHUvG/Q/HLYpsRzRc=</DigestValue></Reference></SignedInfo><SignatureValue>FfWa1AIOdMNCJ0oinMXpL8o87oFSu661LERkaMqRWCDvno+GWbkbSe9Yrj35SszM
d6ykJF9VO/k83R9thBa6pdiQjBdGY1SzCg89QeZna5JciLdMoGcgZcwEK9mfhoke
uWrTiRVEJKjKKbhhzLmRsz0xD02655S/Lf8gMxNo5h0=</SignatureValue><KeyInfo><X509Data><X509Certificate>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</X509Certificate><X509Certificate>MIICnjCCAgegAwIBAgIJAPF+fmqkPJDdMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBBQUAMIGBMQswCQYDVQQGEwJGUjELMAkGA1UECBMCMDYxEDAOBgNVBAoTB0FtYWRldXMxHDAaBgNVBAsTE2Rldi1yZG0tdGtlLWZyYS1wYXkxEDAOBgNVBAMTB1BheVJvb3QxIzAhBgkqhkiG9w0BCQEWFHBheWRlbGRlQGFtYWRldXMuY29tMB4XDTEwMDEyMTEyMDExMFoXDTIwMDExOTEyMDExMFowgY0xCzAJBgNVBAYTAkZSMQswCQYDVQQIEwIwNjENMAsGA1UEBxMETmljZTEQMA4GA1UEChMHQW1hZGV1czEcMBoGA1UECxMTZGV2LXJkbS10a2UtZnJhLXBheTENMAsGA1UEAxMEUGF5MTEjMCEGCSqGSIb3DQEJARYUcGF5ZGVsZGVAYW1hZGV1cy5jb20wgZ8wDQYJKoZIhvcNAQEBBQADgY0AMIGJAoGBAJv6gS421cLaBecYhvP06VgcmwcCRNCon7UPnxmd2NYpctUyZBB56X7XYq3MNZjerz044IKEA4V/dNPbuOMJtr9IpYHr+UO4hAdt1KAsIK9ILjSGPHK6QtHN0bLAKkTa55ZjU3Zfl01vv9umHQTe8ibD5C8TXgYVe/QPJFVLXQKvAgMBAAGjEDAOMAwGA1UdEwQFMAMBAf8wDQYJKoZIhvcNAQEFBQADgYEAb/9OZRzVl99KpUEed0GfaFCq8rXZiwlNyl5HOu4gLzDzMsSgb0zMzABUopArkOwvuz4KPzcPPK31QlPjQ5JL4Z271zxH+pmk3oPgNF+oje/Smk0ZygQGh/lYFor7E/nva0vT1/Lq4917ag+mnfnPbV7hWDOfyGn51J8i7npll04=</X509Certificate><X509Certificate>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</X509Certificate></X509Data></KeyInfo></Signature></Message></ThreeDSecure>
```